# Tool to create a jsFiddle/jsbin.com style code editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, editor

Users of my website have to enter HTML, JavaScript and CSS code snippets. Right now they are simply entering the code snippets in to a simple unstyled `<textarea>`s. I would like to have them enter the code snippets in to boxes that highlight and color code elements similar to jsbin.com and/or jsfiddle.net.

My website is an ASP.net site, so any solution must be compatible with that.

A CSS/JS only solution would be ideal.

I do not need any preview, display or execution ability, simple code color coding in a text editor (textarea?) is all that is required. Commenting highlighting and line numbers would be very nice to have too.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I found several similar questions, but I still have not found an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Check here http://ace.ajax.org/

Comment: If you're willing to implement it yourself, you're looking for a div with `contenteditable` set, and a code highlighting library. Otherwise, your question [could be considered off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question).

Comment: @elclanrs codecademy uses it, wow.

Comment: a similar question was answer here may this helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871949/code-syntax-highlighter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871949/code-syntax-highlighter)

Comment: @winner_joiner, that question is looking for syntax highlighter for code that is output. Not highlighting while inputting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the list of editors on Wikipedia’s [comparison of JavaScript-based source code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors).

I think the most popular editors in that list are [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about) and [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/).

Comment: Thanks, I will check out codeMirror as well.